# Automatically center Japanese ruby text in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, japanese

I have activated Asian Phonetic Guide in LibreOffice to add furigana to Japanese words but every time I open it up, it adds the furigana on the left (which I assume is a result of the style I have that's aligned on the left.)

Is there a way to automatically center the ruby text instead of having to manually change the alignment each time? I tried looking in the Style config itself but didn't find anything.

Comment: My impression is that the horizontal alignment of rubies is not part of a style :(

Answer (score 1):

A *partial workaround* I found is:

1. input all rubies using the default formatting,
2. select the whole text, open Asian Phonetic Guide, select alignment (and other options) and click "Apply".

This will align all the existing ruby text. Unfortunately, it will not apply to any rubies you will input in the future.

Comment: While this isn't yet fully satisfactory, it's good to know, thank you.